# prettyPhoto integration with Sitecore 6.5

Tags: sitecore, prettyphoto

I am trying to load a page on my site into a prettyPhoto lightbox via a click on an anchor tag.  What happens is that it looks like the lightbox begins to load, and it fetches the correct content, but instead of it loading the content in the lightbox, it over writes the whole page.

I tried to load external content in an iframe as well by trying the following:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?iframe=true&width=100&height=100" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]">TEST</a>
```

It brings me to google, moving me away from my site and not loading it into an iframe.

Has anyone had similar problems with this? I am using sitecore 6.5.

Comment: This is not likely a Sitecore-specific issue but rather an issue with the front-end code in your particular project. Something must be forces the full load. Maybe you have JavaScrip that sniffs links and forces a POST to them?

Comment: Thanks for the advice...it is an interesting problem.  I tried to do the inline solution and it works fine, could that still mean there is a scripting issue?